# Do "!" and "nil" give the same result?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In objective-c is the end result of `!variable` the same as `variable==nil` Also I think I read somewhere that iVars are initialized to "nil" (i.e. o) but sadly I can't seem to find where I spotted it now. If I am correct is this initialization to nil part of declaring an iVar or is it linked to something else like @property?

i.e. do these evaluate the same ...

```
if(!myObject) ...
```

and

```
if(myObject == nil) ...
```

Cheers Gary.

**Edited:** hopefully for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question subject and question body appear to be asking different things, so…

To answer the question subject: No, `!` and `nil` are not at all the same. `!` is an operator that returns the logical negation of its operand (that is, `!0` returns `1` and `!` with anything else returns 0), while `nil` is a macro for 0.

To answer the question itself: Yes, `!foo` and `foo == nil` give the same result for object variables. And yes, instance variables are initialized to 0. So are static variables and global variables.

Comment: I think the question was badly worded, I understand they are not the same in terms of operation, I should have been clearer and specified it was the result I was interested in.

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a C logical operator that means *not* (like && means *and* and || means *or*).

`nil` is the way for expressing an unitialized object pointer.

Applied to a pointer, the value of the expression is TRUE whenever the pointer is `NULL` or `nil`.

In the end, `if(!myObject)` and `if(myObject==nil)` have the same behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, what I was getting at was !myObject (gives TRUE or FALSE) and myObject==nil (gives TRUE or FALSE)?

Answer (score 1):

In objective-c the `!` is a boolean operator and returns the opposite of a boolean value or expression result.  In the below example myObj is really evaluating it's pointer value as a boolean, zero or non-zero.  Since myObj is a non-zero pointer this evaluates to true.  !myObj will return the opposite, in this case it would return false.

```
id myObj = nil;
int x = 0;
if (myObj)
  x++;
```

Comment: It is not because "myObj is a valid pointer" that it evaluates to true. It is because it is a non-zero pointer.

Comment: that is what I meant, but you are correct, I didn't type what I meant.  I'll update my answer, thanks.